# extending map with a model implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, extend

I have a rest call json response that looks like:

```
"20412": [
  {
    "username": "foo",
    ...
  },
  ...
],
"20485": [
  ...
```

where the objects in the arrays are `User` model.

I'm trying to create an interface for this json where I could do `assetUsers.get("20412")` and get the users under that.

I've tried simply:

```
export interface AssetUsers extends Map<string, User[]> {}
```

but (when trying to create a mock AssetUsers object using json similar to above) this is giving me a "not assignable" error saying that 20412 does not exist in type AssetUsers.

[Simplified example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAKDirgFdiolMBbYALjkJimQHMBucgF9yoSLEQo0WXHACChYjCJpCcUKiQATVQFlMYADyduSHgBoC9ANoBdAHxk4w8tghJOcJhGwBreYuUoQnZ-YCV6VQBeMkpqACIAJgAGABYAZgBGDLjWK1jqagoC4vi6NEYWHLj0CAg4s3ziwQaSqiLWgriyhmZgKoAjTCh6xoLmxpsW%20OSUgA40hJy8jvaOqi76Cr7WOP6IfpGO8ZXR1o3y3oHMAC9D1uPqSaFyFzdCCAAbYAA6D4geAAUXl8oXCKm%20PDCAMSqSycQAlPC%20EA):

```
export interface User {
    username: string;
}
export interface AssetUsers extends Map<string, User[]> { }

const mockAssetUsers: AssetUsers = {
    "204311":[
        {
            "username":"foo",
        },
        {
            "username":"bar",
        },
    ],
    "204832":[
        {
            "username":"bob",
        },
        {
            "username":"baz",
        },
    ],
}
```

How can I appropriately create a model interface for this json?

Comment: You have to be aware that you are declaring the map keys as number, but the example you are showing above uses string keys instead. I am aware that javascript is really flexible in this regard, but this could be causing the problem.

Comment: @JuanDavid - made the change above, same result though

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m02znw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: You could check this out: http://codebuckets.com/2018/06/17/extending-typescript-to-serialise-map-objects-to-json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get() method returns a specified element from a Map object, the JSON object doesn't have the method get() neither you can assign a map interface to a JSON object.

```
export interface User {
  username: string;
}
export interface AssetUsers extends Map<string, User[]> {}
const mockAssetUsers: AssetUsers = new Map();

mockAssetUsers.set("204311", [
  {
    username: "foo",
  },
  {
    username: "bar",
  },
]);

mockAssetUsers.set("204832", [
  {
    username: "bob",
  },
  {
    username: "baz",
  },
]);

console.log(mockAssetUsers.get("20411"));
```

P.S Maybe this is relevant, but making it that way won't let you use the get() method.

```
const mockAssetUsers: {[key: string]: User[]}
```

Comment: Yea to work with `httpClient.get<AssetUsers>` perhaps i will be unable to extend map and will have to use something like your second method

Comment: You could use the Map constructor with Object.entries ([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAKDirgFdiolMBbYALjkJimQHMBucgF9yoSLDgwAnmDwBBQsRhE0hOAF44AWUxgAPJ25IeAGgL0A2gF0AfAPLYISTnCYRsAa3mLlUQuy-ASvSqGkjAAO5aOgAUAPIARgBWwNgwAHTAKNzAhNEU1HAARABMAAwALADMAIzVhezmlAXU+c1thXRojCz1RegQEIXGTW2Cw21UrRPUHfTdwL2F8ZhQQyPNY+uW4zNl5QAclcW9jdNT00WdDMwL7EsQ8WvTm2fr07NdN4vLAF5PEy9qNshABKEF2BxOCAAG2AaWhEB40VcHgCQRUaR4gWiJQqtUKYL4QA)).

Comment: For use with httpClient in your service, `getAssetUsers(): Observable<AssetUsers>{type A = {[key: string]: User[]}; return this.httpClient.get<A>().pipe(map(x => new Map(Object.entries(x))));}`

Answer (score 0):

Not a interface, but you could declare a type:

```js
type AssetUsers = Map<string, User[]>;
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same result here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAKDirgFdiolMBbYALjkJimQHMBucgF9yoSLDgwAnmDwBBQsRhE0hOAF44AWUxgAPJ25IeAGgL0A2gF0AfAPLYISTnCYRsAa3mLlUQuy-ASvSqGhTUcABEAEwADAAsAMwAjEkRrOaU4dRhWbkRdGiMLGkR6BAQEcaZuYJVuVQ59dT59EXAJQBGmFCV1Vm1fZZ1zbFxABwJUWkZTY1NkQUMzO2sER0QHb1NA7N9TS2Fy52YAF5b9TvUQ0Lk9o6EEAA2wAB0jxA8ABSuHgFBKi8eIFPtF4ikIgBKCF8IA